# SQL Server database not updating ON UPDATE CASCADE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was having trouble getting my `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to function correctly, I get no syntax errors, but whenever my tableA.a1 is updated, there is no change in tableB and I'm not sure what is going on. When showing tableA it has been updated but tableB has not.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA 
(
    a1 int NOT NULL,
    a2 int NOT NULL,
    a3 int NOT NULL,
    a4 varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    a5 TEXT,
    a6 DECIMAL(38,2) NOT NULL,
    CHECK (a6 > -99999.99 AND a6 < 99999.99),
    CHECK (a3 >= 1 AND a3 <= 10),
    PRIMARY KEY (a1,a2) 
);

CREATE TABLE tableB 
(
    b1 int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    b2 int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    b3 int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    b4 char(10) NOT NULL,
    b5 date,
);

INSERT INTO tableB (b4,b5)
VALUES (45, '1980-12-17');

INSERT INTO tableA (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6)
VALUES (1, 2, 1, 4, 'hello', 38.32);

ALTER TABLE tableB WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT b2f 
        FOREIGN KEY (b2, b3) REFERENCES tableA(a1, a2)
             ON DELETE SET DEFAULT 
             ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE tableA WITH NOCHECK
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (a3) REFERENCES tableB(b1);

UPDATE tableA
SET a1 = 5;

SELECT *
FROM tableA;

SELECT *
FROM tableB;
```

Output of data in tables

[image: Output of data in tables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Bad setup

- You have applied `WITH NOCHECK` to disable FK validation and maintenance
- Sample data demonstrate a stillborn "integrity". If you set `WITH CHECK` option - each FK creation would fails with

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "b2f". The conflict occurred in database "db_18_2ea6b", table "dbo.tableA".

#### `FOREIGN KEY (b2, b3) REFERENCES tableA(a1, a2)`

but `(a1=1, a2=2)` and `(b2=(default)1, b3=(default)1)` - how would this work? This is a broken reference!

#### `FOREIGN KEY (a3) REFERENCES tableB(b1)`

but `(a3=4)` and `(b1=(identity)1)` - how would this work? This is a broken reference!

## Solution

1. Fix sample data
2. Put FKs online (`WITH CHECK`)

and it'll work

```
| a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 |    a5 |    a6 |
|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|
|  5 |  1 |  1 |  4 | hello | 38.32 |


| b1 | b2 | b3 |         b4 |         b5 |
|----|----|----|------------|------------|
| (*)|  5 |  1 | 45         | 1980-12-17 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2ea6b/5

Comment: Thank you so much that worked wondrously. I removed no check and used check and that worked great.

Answer (score 0):

because you are updating a1 while your foreign key is a3 in tablea so if you update a3 tableb b1 should change:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET a3 = 5;
select b1 from tableb
```

and if For this assignment you want to change a1 and have b2 be updated to a1's 
so you need to create fk one by one like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (b2) REFERENCES tableA(a1)
FOREIGN KEY ( b3) REFERENCES tableA( a2)
```

not this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (b2, b3) REFERENCES tableA(a1, a2)
```

because this line give both as fk

Comment: For this assignment I specifically want to change a1 and have b2 be updated to a1's value

Comment: I changed my code as you need , I think this should be true.

Comment: So I added in ALTER TABLE tableB WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT b2f FOREIGN KEY (b2) REFERENCES tableA(a1) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET DEFAULT,
FOREIGN KEY (b3) REFERENCES tableA(a2) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET DEFAULT;" It throws there are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'tableA' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'b2f'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 27"

Comment: To be clear both b2 and b3 are foreign keys referencing a1 and a2 primary keys

Comment: @core1211 you first need to drop last fk, and set null values to b2 or value which exist in a1 then you can add your new fk